# environmental variable duplicating in all shells when exporting from a single user

Tags: linux, bash, shell

We have an application where one shell script file maintains all environmental variables, which are set by export. These variables are used to run external commands in the application. So, we have many users running the same application from the single server from their own home directories. When a user A run the application, the executable which are in user B path are running. But we set the environmental variables for each user so the executable is supposed to run from the user A's own path.

How can I make the executable run from the user's own path?

sample.sh

```
export HA_INC=/home/A/proj
export HA_EXE=/home/A/proj/bin
```

these above file is cloned by all users when the application is cloned from git. Whenever the user A is executing a command, which is in HA_EXE directory, the executable is running from some other users' directory. All the users are using their own shells.

Comment: Are those paths set *literally* in that script? Because that is clearly (unless you modify it) going to always use the `/home/A/proj/bin` version of the files. Does each user have the `proj/` directory in their home directories? Does using `$HOME` in those lines not do what you want?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can have a system-wide shell script in /etc/profile.

To represent the current user's home directory, use "~".  To represent B's home directory, use "~B".

Comment: But we do not need system-wide environmental variables to set. We need user-specific env variables but currently these variables are shared by all users. So, executable picks different user's path randomly and starts running.

Comment: Are you saying that each user has their own personal copy of the executable? If so, is what you are asking, is how to launch a specific copy that you select ahead of time, rather than a random one?  I expect I can answer your question but it would help me were you to clarify.

Comment: Yes, each user has his own copy of executable. As a processes of bug fix, each individual makes code changes and wants to run the executable from his own path. But, the executable runs from some other user's executable. So, unable to test the bug fix.